# keeping Google Maps Marker Centered in all viewports

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, responsive-design

Not even sure if the following is possible, haven't found anything yet to confirm either way on the net so far

I am using this to display my map

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"     marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=NP19+7GA&amp;aq=&amp;sll=52.405331,-4.159948&amp;sspn=5.732167,16.907959&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=NP19+7GA,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=51.595904,-2.979781&amp;spn=0.011397,0.033023&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=near&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

It is taken off the google maps webpage as you can probably tell. So far it fills 100% of the screen, which is fine but I am implementing in a responsive website and was wondering if when changing the size of the viewport the marker that is generated can stay centered.

at the moment the map shrinks as the viewport does but you lose sight of the marker (location)

EDIT

If I use the google maps api V3 i can add an event listener like so

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
map.setCenter(homeLatlng);
});
```

Is there a way in Jquery to create this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is javascript, as is the GMaps API. Just put the code above in with your other js.

You could rewrite it to use a jQuery event, but there would be no benefit in doing so.

Comment: feel daft now, but thanks for clarifying, i wasnt sure if i could use the code with just embedding the map in an iframe

Comment: in answer to my own question, no you cant use the code without using the official api

Comment: marked answer as correct as made me realise I have to use the api in order for this to work, pretty crap question really, not sure why i asked :)